# How to merge deleted files from another branch?

Tags: git, merge

I've learned how to merge specific files from another branch from [this link](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/). However, this post does not work for merging deleted files. I've created a git repository to simulate this situation, so you may try this. Here is a example,

```
$git clone https://github.com/gtchoi/SO_question.git
$git branch --track test origin/test
$git checkout test
$git checkout master -- .
$git status

On branch test
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/test'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   a.html
$ls
a.html      b.html      index.html
```

As you and I expected (please see [the repository](https://github.com/gtchoi/SO_question)), compared to the current branch (test), a.html must be added to working tree, so git manages to get a.html from master branch, but b.html is still in the working tree. I'd like to have b.html removed from the working tree since b.html is deleted from master branch. How can I merge deleted files from another branch?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that b got added to the `test` branch independently from the master branch

[image]

If you really just want to make `test` identical to `master` use e.g.

```
$ git reset --soft master 
$ git status
On branch test
Your branch and 'origin/test' have diverged,
and have 3 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    a.html
        new file:   b.html

$ git commit -am 'made identical to master branch'
[test 56ab8cb] made identical to master branch
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 a.html
 create mode 100644 b.html
```